# Use of find command to rename files

Tags: find, mv

I have a list of 10K mp4 files some of which contains a ? mark. I need to replace these with _ (underscore).

I can use find command to find these files but not sure if I can rename them.

```
find . -name "*\?*.mp4" -exec mv {} XXXXXXX \;
```

Looks like I have to iterate through the list returned by find and for each one I need to replace ? with _ but I not sure how to do it.

Comment: [How can I rename all my *.foo files to *.bar, or convert spaces to underscores, or convert upper-case file names to lower case?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `find` for this - whichever way you go with `find` you'll need something like a single `mv` per file. That's a lot of processes, and to no benefit. This is not to mention that it is simply more difficult to do that way. That's my opinion, anyway.

I would use a stream or a batch tool, and tend to prefer `pax`:

```sh
cd -P . && mkdir ../newmp4 &&
pax -rwls'|?|_|g' . "${PWD%/*}/newmp4"
```

If you can create the directory `../newmp4`, that little script will mirror the tree rooted in `.` to the directory just created with hardlinks, but will have replaced every `?` occurring in any filename with an underscore in the meanwhile.

One advantage to this is that *both* trees continue to exist afterward - none of the dentries rooted in the current directory for those files are affected - they are only altered in the mirrored version of the tree. And so you can inspect the results afterward before deciding which version of the tree to  remove. If anything were to go wrong during the operation - there's no harm done.

This does, however, require an fs which supports hardlinks and which has at least as many remaining free inodes as there are child directories of `.` +2, and assumes that `..` `.` and all children of `.` share the same filesystem mount.

Practically the same effect might be got with `rsync`, I think, though I don't believe it is as simply done. If you don't have `pax` *(even if you [really](http://refspecs.linuxbase.org/LSB_3.1.1/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic.html#TBL-CMDS) [should](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html))*, you can just get it. [mirabilos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/43720/mirabilos) maintains the *(to my knowledge)* most [commonly used version](https://www.mirbsd.org/cvs.cgi/src/bin/pax/) on linux systems.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think this just cries out for perl, special character safe and rename is a system call not a fork exec.

```
find . -name "*\?*.mp4" -print0|perl -n0e 'next if /\?.*\//;$o=$_;s!\?!_!g;next if -e;rename $o, $_'
```

Ignores files in directories with ? in their name to prevent undefined behavior and checks for rename conflicts. See below for a detailed explination.

```
find . \               # find files below the current directory
    -name "*\?*.mp4" \ # having a ? in the name and ending in .mp4
    -print0\           # print the file names separated by nulls
|perl \                # direct the output of find to the input of perl
    -n \               # loop over standard input while assigning it to $_
    -0 \               # lines from standard input are separated by null
    -e \               # evaluate the next argument as perl commands
    'next if /\?.*\//; # skip this file if the directory name includes ?
    $o=$_;             # make a copy of the file name of preserve the name
    s!\?!_!g;          # change the ?s in the filename to _s
    next if -e;        # skip file if there is a file by that name
    rename $o, $_'     # do the rename
```

Comment: unfortunately it clobbers _.mp4 if you add the check `-e` ($_ is implied) after the s/// it would skip the conflict. adding revision in a sec.

Comment: the only thing fancy I'm doing with find is the -print0 which uses a null to separate the filenames everything else is handled in perl. the reason I did not use -exec perl is that you hit command line limits, and may call perl for each file and need a more complicated script. the -e check needs to be done in perl after you do the pattern substitution, which i did do in the last edit. I  will add an expanded version for clarity in just a sec.

Comment: let's say ARG_MAX is 255 (I think I've seen this somewhere), that means for every 250 files or so you need another copy of perl. -print0 might hit a limit of 4 gigabytes of file names (and probably not even that since we don't try to seek) in a single perl. Just a hair faster. And I don't have to mess with @ARGV.

Comment: Well, if it matters, the value of [**_POSIX_ARG_MAX**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/limits.h.html) *(which is the minimum conformant value for **ARG_MAX**)* is 4096, and so 255 is probably not a limit you can ever expect to encounter. Still, I accept your point, and I already gave up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`prename`](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/) with `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*\?*.mp4' -exec prename -n 's:(.*/[^?]*)\?(.*$):$1_$2:' {} +
```

`prename -n` will show the files that will be renamed, if you are satisfied with that run the command with removing `-n` (i.e. `prename 's/\?/_/'`).

Comment: Rename could be one of many different binaries, and the default even varies between linux distros. On Debian the default `/usr/bin/rename` is from `util-linux` but on RHEL it's `perl`.

Comment: @jordanm i have clarified the answer..

Comment: That assumes directory names don't contain `?`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Answer edited..

Comment: Not there yet. `(.*$)` would match `(x/?.mp4)` in `./x?x/?.mp4`). And your `g` version won't work.

Comment: @jordanm, isn't it the other way round? I don't remember ever seeing `rename` as being the one from util-linux on Debian.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Could you please take another look ..working for me `./sp?eg/?.mp4 renamed as ./sp?eg/_.mp4` ..i have just blindly put the `g` version this time, i will remove that..

Comment: Oh yes sorry, the first `.*` is greedy. `'s/(.*)\?/$1/'` (also replaces the rightmost `?`) or `s/\?([^/]*)$/$1/`: replace the leftmost one would also work.

Comment: @mikeserv thanks for that..`pax` is not available in Ubuntu by default..i will install it and check..+1 for you :)

Comment: I know it's not! It's ridiculous, too - the Linux Standard Base *requires* it be installed as a core utility *(there's a table of required tools linked at the bottom of my answer)* - but I'm not aware of any distribution which actually does. And the LSB aside, it is also required to be installed on any POSIX-conformant Unix-like system. I don't get - it's way better than `tar` - and it handles `tar` *and* `cpio` files to boot.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I've found to do it is to pipe into something else to generate commands, like `sed`, then execute the commands in `sh`.

```
find . -name '*\?*.mp4' -print | sed 's/.*/"&";h;y/?/_/;x;G;s/\n/ /;s/^/mv /' | sh -s
```

The `find` is pretty self-explanatory, as is the `sh`.  The `sed` command may take a little explanation:

- `s/.*/"&"/` surrounds the input with double quotes to handle any whitespace or special characters;
- `h` copies the buffer to the "hold" buffer, saving a copy;
- `y/?/_/` is the same as `tr \? _` on the command-line;
- `x` swaps the "hold" buffer's contents with the pattern buffer;
- `G` appends the "hold" buffer to the end of the pattern buffer with a '\n' separator; we now have "stringwith?\nstringwith_";
- `s/\n/ /` replaces the newline;
- `s/^/mv /` prepends the `mv` command.

This generates `mv` commands for each file found by `find` with the old name and the new name.

Comment: This is not "easy", nor does it handle all possible file names.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(**/)(*\?*.mp4)' '$1${2//\?/_}'
```

That excludes hidden ones and doesn't look inside hidden directories. It will rename those files regardless of their type (regular, directories, symlink...).

If you also want to consider hidden files/dirs, only rename mp4 files if they're regular files, and be case-insensitive, that would be:

```
zmv '(**/)(*\?*.(#i)mp4)(#q.D)' '$1${2//\?/_}'
```

A GNU approximation (wouldn't check for conflicts and overwrites as `zmv` would):

```
find . -iname '*\?*.mp4' -type f -exec bash -c '
  for file do
    base=${file##*/}
    mv -i "$file" "${file%/*}/${base//\?/_}"
  done' {} +
```